# Import my Personal Profile contact from a vCard

Tags: contacts, privacy

Is there a way or an app to restore my own personal contact (the one available in *Contacts* selecting the *Personal Profile* command) from a VCard (`*.vcf`)?

All contacts can be exported to the SD card (so also the personal one), but importing back the personal vcard put it in standard contact and not in the personal one...

Comment: That's probably the "Me" profile/contact. Have you tried via the Web interface (Google Mail)?

Comment: @Izzy: I didn't find anything useful in the webmail. It looks a more Android-related feature than a Google-related one.

Comment: OK, was worth a try. I do not use that personal profile, so I could not tell.

Comment: Btw: Is root available on the device? On a rooted device, there should be possibilities. As the data are stored somewhere, *Titanium Backup* should be able to catch it. Or one could possibly catch the data with a script utilizing `sqlite` to extract them from their database.

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks for your comment, it let me understand my question wasn't clear. So I refined it. I already use Titanium Backup, so all of my data should be safe and recoverable already. Actually I would like to get my Personal Contact "outta" my phone to be used with other devices and apps. That's the cream in open devices! :>)

Comment: Must it be via vCard? If the intention is to use it as a kind of "business card" to share with others, I might have a much better idea :)

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to have your "personal card" available as a kind of "business card" to easily share with your partners, there might be a much better idea than exporting it as vCard: Export it as QR-Code. So you only need to display that QR-Code on your device, and your partner can use a QR reader to "snap" it. It would then be detected as a "business card" (actually, the QR Code will represent a vCard -- AFAIK even in vCard format), and so your partner can directly import it into his/her contacts.

How to do that? An app I started using a while ago is [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr). It comes with some pretty practical widgets offering shortcuts, and has several add-ons on the playstore for sharing your current GPS position as QR Code, and more... OK, back to topic:

[image: QR Droid business cards] [image: QR Droid History] [image: QR Droid menu]
<sup>QR Droid "business cards", history, selection to create a code (source: [Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwpO3.jpg); click images to enlarge)</sup>

As the screenshots show, this app is able to create "business card QR-Codes". You can even edit them (e.g. embed an image into the code to make it nicer looking). To show it to your partner for scanning, you can easily pick it from the history (second screenshot). And as a side-effect, it can do much more -- not only create, but also read QR Codes.

PS: As the contact will be exported as vCard, you can also share it with *your* other devices this way. It might not be imported to your "personal contact" on the other devices, though...

Answer (score 2):

Select your contact -> Settings menu -> Share -> Gmail -> and send that to your own Email address.

Then you will get a e-mail with yourContact.vcf attached to it. simply download it. (Downloaded file will be available on SDCARD/Download)

Answer (score 0):

download [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&feature=nav_result) from play store and export sms ,contact and app to your email

Comment: Does that Superbackup (could you provide a link, btw?) take care for that personal "Me" profile? igi did not ask for SMS or Apps, but just and especially for that one profile. So I'm not sure whether your suggestion really answers the question.